# Dynamics CRM 2016 Web API Entity Option Sets

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

How do I create an Option Set Item in an already existing Option Set List with the Dynamics CRM 2016 web api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `InsertOptionValueRequest` message, and its corresponding `InsertOptionValue` WebAPI action. See [Request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.insertoptionvaluerequest.aspx) and [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607647.aspx) MSDN pages for details.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply but I do not want to use the CRM SDK. I want to use the REST Service(Web API).

Comment: 2nd link ("Action") has the info you need